# What would this receiver be called?

Tags: receiver

I'm looking at a phase measuring system that uses an amplitude limited version of the received RF signal as a local oscillator to down convert the signal. I've been trying to find a name for this method, along the lines of *hetrodyne*, *homodyne*, and *autodyne*, but none of these seem to fit this configuration.

The input RF is received from multiple elements of a phased array, and one of these elements drives a limiter. (It's assumed that the signal to noise ratio is high enough for this to work.) The limiter output is offset by some fixed frequency and the result is used as a local oscillator to down convert the outputs of each of the antenna elements to the frequency of the offset.

Is there a name for this type of receiver?

Comment: A biphasic  self-flaggilating LOLodyne ;)?

Comment: an up/down Double LO auto offset converter.?

Comment: An F’d up double hetero/homodyne converter?

Comment: A coherent anaphrodidic demodulator.

Comment: That's a Homodyne.

Comment: @KevinWhite I'd say it's rather heterodyne, because the target frequency is not 0 Hz

Comment: Sounds a *bit* like a Wadley loop that offsets the incoming RF frequency to cancel out oscillator drift.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - OK. The first and second paragraphs ask slightly different questions. The first one doesn't mention offsetting the frequency.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes.  The detail with the offset is the actual implementation. The result is that all signals down convert to that offset frequency (rather than baseband).

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of question of perspective:

- From a point of outcome, and the existence of an intermediate frequency oscillator (limited signal·fixed frequency oscillation), it's an heterodyne receiver
- The fact that you're using a nonlinearly distorted reception itself to mix down, and then preserve the IF through filtering it's kind of an envelope detector (but that is a very high-level comparison)
- From my point of implementation view, your single branch that you use for mixing is used to find the exact RF frequency, so that your receiver can work with a local oscillator that doesn't "know" the transmit frequency. From that point of view, it's a heterodyne receiver with carrier-recovery frequency correction.